# Rails 4 Update Collection For Current User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-update

I am trying to update a collection of objects belonging to the current user.

Is there a way to use update_all and also check they belong to the current user like so?

```
Object.where(user_id: current_user.id, id: params[:id]).update_all(..)
```

Or is it better to do that by fetching the objects first

```
current_user.objects
```

And then iterate to update?

Answer (score 0):

Both are fine, really, but I don't get why you perform an `update_all` if you search by `id`, like `id: params[:id]`, that probably yields one record only.

Notice that, if you add an has_many relationship from user to `objects`, in case user it's deleted, `object.user_id` is set to `nil`. You might want to decide based on this knowledge if you want a `has_many` or stick with the query you've built, which is perfectly fine.

Comment: The params I pass to that method are an array containing the object ids, to be reordered (they have a position attribute). So basically all the objects belonging to the current user are updated with that method.

That's why actually I was thinking to check if the ids passed as params match the current user objects ids with something like

params[object_ids] - current_user.objects.pluck):id == []

Comment: Ok let's put it in this way, if you want to update all those `objects` (the one you would fetch using params[:object_ids]), to the **same values**, which can be something like `update_all(position: 1)`, you just have to use `where(id: params[:object_ids], user_id: current_user.id)`, if you want to set different position for each supplied record (which is what I think you want), you cannot do that in a single query, you have to loop over all those elements and perform a single query for each one

Comment: Second option indeed. By checking if the ids match with the pluck (in my previous comment), and then if they do, loop and update, there is at least the performance gain of not looping through the ids, fetch individually with the id, and then update individually, right?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding your code at this point, but if params[:object_ids] are ids of current_user.objects, that subtraction will always be empty (but I'm not even sure why you were showing that code). That being said, best way to handle what you want is simple: `Object.where(user_id: current_user.id, id: params[:object_ids]).find_each { |obj| obj.position = whatever; obj.save }`, preloading records "all" together is much more performant than multiple queries and [find_each](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/ClassMethods/find_each) ensures you won't overload your server

Comment: Thank you for your help. The goal of that substraction was to check that all the object ids were passed and that they were all the right ones : when the positions change, all the objects are updated so technically with your method only a sub array of the object ids could be passed as params and thus the positionning would not be correct..

Comment: Uhm, won't `Object.where(user_id: current_user.id)` be enough in that case, so? (You need to create some business logic to avoid that table to grow too much per-user)

Comment: It's enough to check if they re all the current user's. But if the client passes [1,2] whereas the object ids are [1,2,3], positions are messed. The objects should not be much since they re profile pictures, (so on average not more than 4 or 5)

Comment: Mhhh I'm sorry, I need to see some code to better understand this. Do you want to fetch the objects and then the fetched object position is basically `params[:object_ids] = [1,2,3]; object.position = params[:object_ids].index(object.id)` ?